# Cassandra load after adding a node differs

Tags: cassandra

Recently i added a 3rd node to 2 node cluster. New node auto-boostraped without errors. Before adding load on both nodes was around 350gb(have keyspace with replication factor 2). I was expecting load on new node to be around 2/3 of initial load something like 230gb but its much smaller around 190gb. Did repair and clean up on one of original nodes and it dropped to close to 180. Is this normal behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is normal.

Your initial nodes probably had stale data that wasn't transferred.